# Adding complex measures in MDX

Tags: mdx, iccube

I have successfully added basic sum/count/etc.. simple measures, but have no idea how to add more complex one.

Let's assume that data structure represent tracks with goods and have next structure:

- date
- id_track
- id_articte
- amount
- cost

And want to calculate next measures:

1. average item price, calculated as sum(cost) / sum(amount)
2. average track cost. It's average between sum(cost) for whole tracks. Sql expression looks like sum(cost) / count(distinct id_track)

What is the right way to add this measures to my cube, in case i will need them in Excel over XMLA?

Answer (score 3):

Complex calculation are solved using what we call in MDX '*calculated measures*'.

*Calculated Measures* support the whole power of MDX language. You can see more information about Calculated Measures [here](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Calculated%20Members.php).  They are very powerful and over 100 functions are supported ([function list](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/functions.php)).

If you want to define a calculated measure once per schema I'd advise defining them in Advanced/Scripts in the Builder UI tab. You can first check validity in the MDX IDE and once validated move them to the Script.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I have successfully added one of them and stuck with second. I can't find how to write big and nice comments, so i have updated my question with more details

Answer (score 1):

> average item price, calculated as sum(cost) / sum(amount)

This would look something like the following:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[AvgPrice] AS
  AVG(
    EXISTING([Item].[Item].MEMBERS)
   ,[Measures].[COST]
  )
...
```

Or

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[AvgPrice] AS
  [Measures].[COST] 
  / 
  [Measures].[AMOUNT] 
...
```

> average track cost. It's average between sum(cost) for whole tracks.
>   Sql expression looks like sum(cost) / count(distinct id_track)

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[AvgTrackCost] AS
  AVG(
    EXISTING([TrackItem].[TrackItem].MEMBERS)
   ,[Measures].[COST]
  )
...
```

I've had to guess that the following exist within your cube:

```
[Measures].[COST]
[Measures].[AMOUNT] 
[Item].[Item].MEMBERS
[TrackItem].[TrackItem].MEMBERS
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. I have successfully added one of them and stuck with second. I can't find how to write big and nice comments, so  i have updated my question with more details